# Shopify : Hide checkout button by product tag in cart

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

I want to hide the cart button when there are products with the Pre-order product tag and the Regular product tag in the cart.

This code, we were able to get the tags for all products in the cart.

```
{% for item in cart.items %}
    {% assign carttag = item.product.tags %}                
    <p>{{ carttag }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

However, the following code does not work.

```
  {% if carttag contains 'Preorder' and carttag contains 'Regular' %}
    <p>Stop!</p>               
  {% else %}
     <input type="submit" name="checkout"> 
  {% endif %}
```

How can I handle all looping values ​​as one?

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right path, but your code has 2 problems.

1. You are overriding Cart Tags value for each product. So, you always have Product tags for last product in your cart.
2. **product.tags** return Array while you are treating it as string.

Fixing these issues your code will look like

```
{% assign cartTags = "" %}

{% for item in cart.items %}
    {% assign joinedTags = item.product.tags | join: " " %}                
    {% assign cartTags = cartTags | append:" " | append:joinedTags %}
{% endfor %}

{% if cartTags contains 'string1' and cartTags contains 'string2' %}
    {{cartTags}}
{% endif %}
```

What I have done here is, initialized an empty variable named cartTags. Then for each product in the cart, I convert the tags array to string using join filter and add them to all tags using append filter.

[Product Tags](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/objects/product#product-tags)

[Join Filter](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/join/)

[Append Filter](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/append/)

Comment: Hi,Thank you for the advice. It worked as expected. I will continue learning about code